# integrating the user location doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, location, google-maps-flutter

I tried to build an application, which shows the current user location. In order to achieve this goale, I used Google-Map and location plug-in. I tried a sample I found in the internet, but I get an error and don't know why... I think I did it the same like the guy in the video did it...

This is the ode I tried:

```
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
    _location.onLocationChanged().listen((l) {
      _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(target: LatLng(l.latitude, l.lomgitude), zoom: 10)));
    });
  }

 child: GoogleMap(
     markers: markers,
     initialCameraPosition: position,
     mapType: MapType.hybrid,
     onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
     myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
  ),
```

This is the error I get:

```
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:42:32: Error: 'onLocationChanged' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.
    _location.onLocationChanged().listen((l) {
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Does anybody find my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `()` of `onLocationChanged()` 
please change from

```
_location.onLocationChanged().listen((l) {
  _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(l.latitude, l.lomgitude), zoom: 10)));
});
```

to

```
_location.onLocationChanged.listen((l) {
  _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(l.latitude, l.lomgitude), zoom: 10)));
});
```